# Trying to delete a table from a database with a php file

Tags: php, javascript, localhost

I've got a table in the database mshop2, named userdb. It has columns:

- ID
- name
- username
- password
- email

My js file with all the functions stored in them is named mshop2.script, where me deleteUser function is also stored, which will jump to a file named deleteUser.php

The php file where I want the code to run on is admin.php and It's got these written in it:

```
<font color="white">Deletion - ID</font>
<input class="test1" type="text" id="txUserid" value="">
<input class="test2" name="Submit" type="submit" value="" id="submit" 
       onClick='deleteUser();txUserid.value="";'/>
```

the 'input class' words are just going to match an image folder according to my css file to show an image that I want the code to run on when I click it so don't mind it.
I have included these lines in the head of my .php file:

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='mshop2.script.js'></script>
```

I've written this on my mshop2.script.js file:

```
function deleteUser(){
    var userid = $('#txUserid').val();
    var finalData = {
        uid: userid
    };

    $.post('deleteUser.php', finalData, function(resp){
        if(resp == 'success'){
            alert('User successfully deleted.');
            getUserList();
        }
    }); 
}
```

This is the contents of my deleteUser.php file:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["userid"]);
    $q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$uid'";

    if(!mysql_query($q, $con)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        echo mysql_error();
    }else{
        echo 'success';
    }

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Nothing is happening and if I enter '1' into the text box or any number from 1 to 5 the matching line in my table in database with the same ID that I entered won't get deleted.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a jumbled variable and that confuse u.

In your script code, you had passed `uid` with a value of `userid`
And you access a wrong variable in your `deleteUser.php`

Instead of `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);`

change to `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);`

And in your query, just change the variable `$uid` to `$id`

Just use a a similar variable to what had you passed in your script so that it will not be hard on your part to see common mistakes

EDIT:::
Try this
Remove the onclick event on your html code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(function() { 
          $(".test2").click(function() { 
                 var id = $("#tsUserid").val();
                 $.post("deletUser.php", { id: id }, function(data) { 
                     alert(data);
                 });
          });
     });
 </script>
```

Your php will be your deleteUser.php and just

change `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);`

to `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);`

and your query to 
`$q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$id'";`

Hope it helps.

Comment: did that and nothing happened :(

Comment: Try what i had edited because i know you are passing also to your function an empty value.

Comment: oh wow it worked!!Thank you! Could you please please explain to me what you did there?:D I'd really like to learn about what you did there :D but also, I've got these 2 other buttons which are update and adding new users and It will give that 'success' message no matter which button I click, like if my add new button produces a 'user successfully added' message, the 'success' message from deleteUser will be there in the background :/ and even if I enter a deleted ID into the text box it will still say 'success'

Comment: If it works then how about a green check.. I cant explain you piece by piece but you can refer to jquery documentation, your two other buttons will have the same code.. what you will change is those variables to be pass corresponding to what fields will you access, and your query also, if you will add then make a query for add then so on. Thank you

Comment: yea works :p but that code keeps on running no matter what I click and I don't understand the contents of that link you gave me because I got mine from my teacher.

Comment: nvm I figured it out now, works perfectly, thanks a lot, ignore my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Change this :-

```
$q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$uid'";
```

to

```
$q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$id'";
```

You are catching the value in variable $id and using $uid in the sql statement that's the reason its not working.

Comment: still not working. I've changed:-    $q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$uid'"; into     $q = "DELETE FROM userdb WHERE ID = '$id'"; and nothing happened, also, I tried to change     var finalData = {
    uid: userid
}; into      var finalData = {
    id: userid
}; and nothing happened as well

Answer (score 1):

in jq in are posting uid.

change post to

```
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uid"]);
```